# Minimum supported Gradle version is 7.2. Current version is 7.1

Tags: android, gradle

I'm developing a flutter plugin for anroid and when I try to compile my build.gradle in android studio but when it compiles it throws my the
following error:

**Minimum supported Gradle version is 7.2. Current version is 7.1.
Please fix the project's Gradle settings.
Gradle Settings.**

When I update the version in my build.gradle it throws me the same error but whit the new version. The project didn't generate me a gradle wrapper properties files whe i use the following commands:

**fvm flutter create --template=plugin plugin-name**

**fvm flutter create -t plugin --platforms android .**

The following is my build.gradle file

```
group 'com.example.scan'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

rootProject.allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 18
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation files('src/libs/libscanner.jar')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

go to `Android Studio -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Gradle`
then check in `Gradle Project` section that `Use Gradle from - Specific location` defined correct for your system. After apply changes and **rerun build**

```
Starting Gradle Daemon...
...
```

this works for me.